# data-toggle="collapse" menu disappears when you click it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

My `data-toggle="collapse"` menu disappears when it is clicked.

Although it does dropdown as required, whenever a user clicks anywhere on the dropdown menu, it disappears.

What am I doing wrong ? Here is my code:

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bg-dark " href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    My Account
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">Other info goes here... //before the closing div
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `data-target` attribute so that Bootstrap knows which one to drop down.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bg-dark" href="#" data-target="#navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   My Account
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="navbarDropdown1" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">Other info goes here... //before the closing div
```

Comment: dropping down is not the problem, its when it drops down and I click anywhere in the dropdown menu, it disappears